# Typescript, how to use a constructor of a class extending an abstract class as parameter

Tags: typescript

I have an abstract class `A`. Then I have two classes, `B` and `C`, that extend that abstract class.

(Example code):

```js
abstract class A {
    private name: string;

    abstract saluto(): void;

    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class B {
    saluto(): void {
        console.log(`Hello ${this.name}`);
    }

    constructor(name: string) {
        super(name);
    }
}

class C {
    saluto(): void {
        console.log(`Ciao ${this.name}`);
    }

    constructor(name: string) {
        super(name);
    }
}
```

I have a function that given the array `const generators = [B, C]` and a parameter returns me the instances of `B` and `C` created passing the parameter to the constctor.

For instance:

```js
const generators = [B, C];

function generate(generators: typeof A[], name: string): A[] {
    return generators.map(gen => new gen(name)); // Here I have the error
}
const instances = generate(generators, 'Eugenio');
```

Here I have an error, because it says `Cannot create an instance of an abstract class.`.

How can I solve this problem? There should be a way to tell to tsc that the generators are not A itself but non-abstract classes that extends it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `typeof A`, you basically create a type similar to `abstract new(name: string) => A`. The `abstract` keyword on a constructor (TS 4.2 [abstract constructor signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#abstract-construct-signatures)) marks this class/constructor as not instantiable. So, if you want an instantiable class, you need to type it without the `abstract new` and just `new` ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)):

```
function generate(generators: (new(name: string) => A)[], name: string): A[] {
    return generators.map(gen => new gen(name)); // No error anymore
}
```

**Edit:** Automatically infer constructor signature.

To do this, you usually would use [ConstructorParameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#constructorparameterstype), but this is not possible since `typeof A` returns an abstract constructor, and ConstructorParameters only works for normal constructors. Thus we have to type that utility type ourselves using [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggg3gKAUIQAcoB7CAU3koBMEA7YAW0oC4FIoBLBgcwDceAkVBc4iMMGQBXCGQAUASg4A3Mt1pCRhWGQZcZ8MlAVNWHLrz4AaBMCh8ATJejW7DvgGYODGcxBKKCVcHSJCCAALbjAAOnNKBABeRhZKIXCAXzxsvBQ0DAAhBEoADyoGWgxsfHCpWXllNQ16WvCiPQMyZEpY5DI+BQADAAlKZH6EABIcKJj4tMyhpQyiXPDOw2NTBNcefg9HF043A-tHH0Z-QODQ9qIwGWIgszTD53evFbDs3Pz0BAAYRK5UolWqbUI9TkihUCHUmju9yQ+jA3V6-UGQ0B3GAZGms2icQSS2+WWEG1R0CM8h2aT27nOzgZZ08lz8ASCIUh7UezzprHeTk+ZLWOWEEAAns8EFRIMlZdLKGQAGZYbSbRB8MFBYC0jApADahTsgIAutopTLMOBoBJAVSoDSTAAFBxpKhQMAAHgAKgA+BW+kEVKr2W0weCMSgAdwUsQTnjAHF4KqCCBdISSgeADElCAA-BmEL5KKogpalRn3axPWAAPIq7ApG3ieAOgzU7ZumC1oI+q3KtWYf3aFUyBjwbj6BDahi6qgKOcLkzJhBmWPxxOONc9j39xuYLOBo+Gs12BOxJMcPd9r2HuGYM9IwhQSgQGRQBiznUwfWxZhgGIJcwWSQN5xjH8GC3K8dyUFYEAAekQhAADl8SCcgoHsPNmBMShxU1BBeEgXNYEoA0oIXSgQPnP9VzsAByABRGQ52nRimLlCBOIQABWFYgA)):

```
type AbstractConstructorParameters<T> = T extends abstract new(...args: infer P) => any ? P : never;

type ParametersOfA = AbstractConstructorParameters<typeof A>;

function generate(generators: (new(...args: ParametersOfA) => A)[], ...args: ParametersOfA): A[] {
    return generators.map(gen => new gen(...args)); // No error anymore
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. However it does not automatically get `A`'s constructor's signature. I mean, because `A`'s constructor has the signature `(string) => A`, is there a more concise way that makes me avoid writing the signature after `new`?

Comment: I've updated the question with a way to infer the constructor signature.